# Android custom camera with autofocus

Tags: android

I have been making an android app that requires camera with autofocus enabled like photomath app on Android market is there any easy way to do that I am not asking to make app like photomath I am just asking the camera.

Comment: what minimum sdk version you are targeting. depending on that you have 2 options that I can present

Comment: anything that works is welcomed bro.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call autoFocus() method of the camera object, and register a callback function to run when the camera is focused.

Your question is well explained in this article:
http://android-er.blogspot.com.ng/2011/01/start-camera-auto-focusing-autofocus.html?m=1

Comment: but I don't want to focus all the picture I want a little box that is only focused like the app in the link which is photomath https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C9274676502

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and the comment on the answer posted my ayz4sci. You will have to go for a embedded camera application which you will have to write on your own.

The functionality that you see in photomath not just auto focus, There are lot of image processing stuff going on.

I suggest you to look at,

1. OPEN CV for image processing stuff (There can be many not just this).
2. Android Camera2 API to write your own embedded camera application ([Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) is the link to a sample project).